# Why composer does not install my app

Tags: php, json, installation, composer-php, packagist

I am new with composer and i am just trying to make a composer file and make my product to be downloadable via composer, i have registered in [packagist](https://packagist.org) site and uploaded my product [there](https://packagist.org/packages/dariushha/zinux).

I have the following details in my `composer.json` file.

```
{
    "name": "dariushha/zinux",
    "type": "framework",
    "description": "A simple and lightweight but powerful framework supporting MVC design pattern",
    "license": "MIT",
    "version": "4.1.4",
    "homepage": "http://dariushha.github.io/zinux/",
    "keywords": ["PHP","MVC","lightweight","powerful", "design pattern", "zinux", "simple"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Dariush Hasanpoor",
            "email": "b.g.dariush@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/dariushha"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php":    ">=5.5.8"
    }
}
```

But when i run `composer install` it only create the following filesystem tree structure:

```
   .
   |-vendor
   |---composer
```

It was suppose to create a subdirectory `zinux` as well.
What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the composer information for your project, there's nothing to install as php is the only requirement and your framework is the thing that needs to be installed. You need to create a new project if you want to "install" your framework.

To create a new project, based on your framework, you can do the following:

- Create an empty directory
- Create, inside that directory, a file named "composer.json"
- Inside that file, put the following

  `{
      "require": {
          "dariushha/zinux": "dev-master"
      }
  }`
- Now enter `composer install` and a `vendor/zinux` directory with your framework will be created.

Comment: Thanks, but it gave me that `- The requested package dariushha/zinux could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
` which [exists](https://packagist.org/packages/dariushha/zinux), what is wrong?